# ActionScript compiler

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, compiler-construction

are there any compilers for ActionScript 3 under *nix like systems or appropriate toolkit to work with Flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Haxe](http://haxe.org/) does not compile AS3, but it DOES cross-compile to Flash compatible SWF/SWCs (amongst many other things).

Answer (score 8):

The [Flex SDK](http://incubator.apache.org/flex/) compiler — `mxmlc` — will also compile plain ActionScript code.

Comment: Good news too, using flex sdk stack is more efficient by the way haXe gives us a really robust toolkit pack in addition to flex sdk.

http://haxe.org/doc/intro